# How do plants store energy by potassium battery?

Tags: plant-physiology, electrophysiology, bioenergetics, energy-metabolism

Plants have a so-called potassium battery system for energy storage/conversation. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium-ion_battery) only has a reference to a technical article. Can someone explain it in a layman's language (or refer to a non-technical article)?

Comment: Oof, I'm not much of a fan of that Wikipedia article's segue to a "biological potassium battery" since the mechanism and purpose is totally different. The cited article is fine but the summary in Wikipedia is taking a statement in the article way too literally.

Comment: @BryanKrause I guess that wikipedia page is not properly curated. It also says that Prussian Blue is a potassium compound (it is Fe₄[Fe(CN)₆]₃)

Comment: @WYSIWYG Good catch, I hadn't really looked at the quality of the rest of the page. Yet another reminder to be a bit careful with Wikipedia...

Answer (score 6):

I'll give it a layman's attempt in sort of an "ELI5" approach. I hope the analogy isn't too simplistic, and please don't take it too literally.

**How do plants use K<sup>+</sup>?**

Plants control K<sup>+</sup> concentrations and do work within the plant by pumping K<sup>+</sup> between different compartments. Because water tends to follow solute concentrations (osmosis), plants can do things like suck in water simply by moving potassium around.

(note: animal cells do something similar: this is how your nervous system, kidneys, digestive tract, and other cells/organs perform their functions, but using different ions or combinations of ions)

**Analogy to some human activities**

Moving all this K<sup>+</sup> around takes a lot of energy. Creating a concentration gradient is a lot like pumping water uphill: you put some energy in, but you are storing that energy as *potential energy* for the water flowing back downhill, or the ions flowing back against their concentration gradient (or water flowing the other way). But normally, plants use this as a way to *spend energy to do useful things*, rather than a way to store it. It's like they are pumping the water up the hill and then floating useful ores or lumber on a boat as it flows back down the hill.

**What is actually happening that Wikipedia describes as a plant "K<sup>+</sup> battery"**

The article cited on Wikipedia, though, [Gajdanowicz et al 2011](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/2/864), shows that sometimes plants take advantage of the mobility of potassium ions to *assist the H<sup>+</sup> ATPase* that is another form of energy storage. Plants use H<sup>+</sup> (proton) concentration gradients similarly to how they use K<sup>+</sup> concentration gradients, but they are used to power different processes in the plant. Sort of like two different types of batteries.

**Return to the analogy, and why this is useful to the plant**

Normally both H<sup>+</sup> gradients and K<sup>+</sup> gradients are powered by ATP, which is indirectly produced via photosynthesis: think of it like the plant's coal-fired power plant. Converting K<sup>+</sup> concentration gradients to H<sup>+</sup> concentration gradients would be like using the water you pumped up the hill to power a hydroelectric plant that is charging a car battery. The benefit for the plant is that, because K<sup>+</sup> can be easily moved around, the plant is able to power those hydroelectric plants anywhere around the hill, and that can be advantageous if a particular part of the plant is low on other sources of energy.